# how to prevent other account(including root) into my directory on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Update: May I use some software to encrypt my folder so that anyone cannot enter that folder? Don't compress that folder, I want to do `crontab -e` in that folder. I don't want anyone else to revise my crontab. 
I wan to create a directory on raspberry Pi(linux OS on it). But I don't want any other account can `cd mydirectory`. Even though I use `mkdir .folder` to hide it,root account can use `ls -a` to find it. Is there any method of forbidding other account to `cd` to my folder? Or when they want to enter, they need to input the password ? By the way, I don't have root privilege.

Comment: This question belongs on Superuser or Unix Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent root from doing anything.  No exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The root user can log into the account of any user without a password. Therefore, there is no way to create a folder that is invisible to the root user (or that they can't read) without some other method, such as encryption using [`gpg`](https://www.gnupg.org/).

```
$ whoami
user
$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for user: 
# whoami 
root
# su - user
$ whoami
user
```

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117150/can-root-superuser-read-my-read-protected-files)